# Полный вариант известной поговорки. Пунктуация.

Tags: пунктуация

Ни рыба ни мясо. Запятая не ставится.

А как быть с полным вариантом этой поговорки? Как поставить знаки?

Ни рыба (?) ни мясо(?) ни кафтан(?) ни ряса.

Comment: мне с точкозапятой вариант понравился. И всё. последний - вообще странный. Сам попробуй произнести просто. Знаки препинания - чтобы читать было понятно. Прочти своё

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Niemand - да. 
Поговорка распадается на половинки, каждая из которых может рассматриваться как подпадающая под правило о запятой, которая не нужна при союзе "ни...   ни..." с двумя противопоставляемыми и взаимодополняющими частями. 
Можно, конечно, и всё через запятые, но тогда акцент другой: вроде как в ряд ставится мясо и кафтан. Не очень реально, что автор так мыслит.

По Далю и семантику-то с этимологией опасно проверять, а уж пунктуацию...

Answer (score 6):

Ни рыба ни мясо, ни кафтан ни ряса.

Answer (score 2):

В Толковом словаре В.И.Даля все слова через запятую : *ни рыба, ни мясо, ни кафтан, ни ряса.* В сегодняшних публикациях возможен вариант с постановкой тире между двумя частями поговорки : *ни рыба, ни мясо - ни кафтан, ни ряса*. Поскольку в таком полном виде поговорка уже никем и никогда не употребляется, все эти мелочи не имеют никакого значения. Нам хватает выражения "ни рыба ни мясо".

Comment: Ни за что не поставил бы три запятые. Сразу получается как бы буквальный смысл. Да и тире тоже... Противопоставлением попахивает, а его там и близко нет.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ. Но полные варианты известных поговорок пока ещё вызывают интерес. На олимпиадах просят завершить фразу, на уроках литературы даётся задание продолжить поговорку и записать. Мне на стену ВК бросили несколько примеров полных вариантов. Запятая там стояла даже в первой части, между "рыбой" и "мясом"). Я её удалила, а потом задумалась. Так что интерес не праздный.

Comment: Ни рыба ни мясо - уже не народная поговорка, а т.н. "устойчивое выражение", поэтому без запятой. В полной форме поговорку следут приводить по старым источникам, то есть по Далю. А право автора в своем тексте - как угодно написать :  
>А. П. Чехов. Неприятность (1888)  
**Он ни мужик, ни барин, ни рыба, ни мясо**; прошлое у него горькое, в настоящем у него только 25 рублей в месяц, голодная семья и подчиненность, в будущем те же 25 рублей и зависимое положение, прослужи он хоть сто лет.

Comment: Так и евреи говорят, ни рИба ни мясо...местячковое произношение и подражание их акценту. И нечего выдавать это за норму языка.  Ни фонтан, ни речка, в смысле нормальной речи. Малороссийская мова--не=ни, и ее влияние. Пущай кто оспорит.
Насчет пунктуации, она подразумевается, опять же нормами пунктуации 19 века, следование двух отрицаний--это перечисление, через запятую.
За безграмоное отношение к норме-это к корректорам, пропустившим в печать.
А за бездумное отношение к самой сути языковых оборотов, минус всем тем, кто это в норму возводит.

Answer (score 1):

А я бы вот так написал:

Ни рыба - ни мясо, ни кафтан - ни ряса.

Answer (score 0):

Да, есть правило не ставить запятую в сравнительных оборотах с использованием устойчивых словосочетаний.
Но относится ли это правило к самой поговорке? Почему поговорка должна подпадать под правила цитирования самой себя?
Если в живой речи в качестве эпитета используется первая часть этой поговорки, запятые (по тому правилу) не нужны. Если же полностью — я применил бы уже предлагавшийся вариант с одной запятой (*ни рыба ни мясо, ни кафтан ни ряса*).
И думаю, что в самой поговорке нужны более основательные знаки препинания, причём не в виде трёх запятых, а такие, которые разграничивали бы две противопоставляемые пары, между которыми есть соответствующая речевая пауза.
Например:
*Ни рыба, ни мясо; ни кафтан, ни ряса.

Ни рыба, ни мясо. Ни кафтан, ни ряса.*

Comment: Это уже на совести тех, кто эту норму и пропихивает.  не=ни, и историческую заморочку со связью с малороссийским говором русского языка. Время рассудит.